# Photon Sphere Planck Recalibration

Tags: visible-light, black-holes, photons, metric-tensor, geodesics

Say a black hole's Schwarzchild radius is equal to the Planck length then a horizontal formula can be established as

$A = 4\pi \ell^2$

[1]. I've tried to find an analogue of this set up online but can't find any reading material on it. I'll expand further on this at the end and ask a few questions.

We start with the equation for the Schwarzschild radius:

$R_s = \frac{2Gm}{c^2}$

where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $m$ is the mass of the black hole, and $c$ is the speed of light.

If the black hole has a Schwarzschild radius equal to the Planck length, we have:

$\frac{2Gm}{c^2} = \ell_P$

Solving for the mass, we get:

$m = \frac{\ell_P c^2}{2G}$

Next, we use the equation for the radius of the photon sphere:

$R_p = \frac{3}{2}R_s$

Substituting in the expression for $R_s$, we have:

$R_p = \frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{2Gm}{c^2} = \frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{2G}{c^2}\cdot\frac{\ell_P c^2}{2G} = \frac{3}{2}\ell_P$

So the radius of the photon sphere in this case is indeed 1.5 times larger than the Planck length, as expected. Then a standard formula would be

$R_p > \frac{3}{2}R_s = \frac{2Gm}{c^2} = \frac{3}{2}R_s$

I have a few questions, this 1.5 difference, can't it simply be calculated, given that you know $R_p$ as

$R_p - \frac{3}{2}R_s$

Well I took a look, its generally said the photon sphere follows

$R_P = \frac{3Gm}{c^2} = \frac{3}{2}R_s$

instead of the usual

$R_s = \frac{2Gm}{c^2}$

Can anyone explain how you obtain these two different results? And why in the formula

$R_P = \frac{3Gm}{c^2} = \frac{3}{2}R_s$

We have a 2 in the denominator on the far RHS but only a 3 in the numerator other middle expression? I would have thought if

$R_s = \frac{2Gm}{c^2}$

Then

$R_s = \frac{(3 \cdot 2)Gm}{2c^2}$

Would lead to...

$R_P = \frac{3Gm}{c^2}$

Right?

Going back now to,

$A = 4\pi \ell^2$

Surely this would be the smallest area that is computable within physics, since physics breaks down below the Planck scales? I've been trying to visualise such a small object and the immense curvature it should possess as posed by general relativity. I took my sights to using the spacetime uncertainty,

$\Delta x\ c\ \Delta t \geq \ell^2_P$

we can state that this equation be taken to the Planck domain as the shortest interval or length:

$ds^2 = g_{tt}\ \Delta x\ c\Delta t \geq \ell^2_P$

And of course, the equation can undergo a curve in the pseudo Reimannian manifold, which is akin to a curve between two Planck regions,

$ds^2 = g\ \Delta x\ c\Delta t \geq \ell^2_P$

Using the spacetime uncertainty,
$\Delta x\ c\ \Delta t \geq \ell^2_P$
we can state that this equation be taken to the Planck domain as the shortest interval or length:

$ds^2 = g_{tt}\ \Delta x\ c\Delta t \geq \ell^2_P$

And of course, the equation can undergo a curve in the pseudo Reimannian manifold, which is akin to a curve between two Planck regions,

$ds^2 = g\ \Delta x\ c\Delta t \geq \ell^2_P$

The metric can be rewritten as

$ds^2 = g\ \Delta x\ c\Delta t = g(\Delta \mathbf{q}_1 \Delta \mathbf{q}_2) \geq \ell^2_P $

Where $\mathbf{q}$ is the infinitesimal displacement by generalised coordinates which acts on the integral as $\mathbf{q}(\lambda_1)$ and $\mathbf{q}(\lambda_2)$

$ds = \int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2} d\lambda \sqrt{|ds^2|}$

Can this describe the surface of the black hole in terms of its curvature along a line element?

Any insights as well into more specific and maybe better derivatives into the photon sphere would be much appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185939/123208

Comment: If you want to know why the photon sphere radius is $\frac32r_s$, I have most of the details here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/680961/123208

Comment: Thanks, I just had a few more questions in the OP, such as the parameterized curve on a Planck length.