# Why would spherical velocity be zero along a numerically-integrated null geodesic?

Tags: computational-physics, geodesics, software

I am writing a numerical solver for the null geodesics of an arbitrary spacetime metric, but currently mostly targetting black hole spacetimes. I am attempting to numerically integrate the geodesic equations:

$$
\frac{d^2 x^\mu}{ds^2} = -\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha \beta} \frac{dx^\alpha}{ds} \frac{dx^\beta}{ds}
$$

Given $c = G = 1$, $M = 15000$, and initial conditions $x^\mu = \langle 0, 6M, \frac{\pi}{4}, 0\rangle$ and $v^\mu = 
\left \langle \frac{r_0^2 + a^2}{\Delta}, -1, 0, \frac{a}{\Delta} \right \rangle$, this is the code of my solver:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

def calculate_christoffel(jacob, g_inv, dims):
    # based on https://github.com/AndreaAntoniali/Riemann-tensor-calculator/blob/main/Riemann_Calculations.ipynb
    gamma = np.zeros((dims, dims, dims))
    for beta in range(dims):
        for mu in range(dims):
            for nu in range(dims):
                for alpha in range(dims):
                    gamma[beta,mu,nu] = 1/2 * g_inv[alpha][beta] * (jacob[alpha][mu][nu] + jacob[alpha][nu][mu] - jacob[mu][nu][alpha])
    return gamma

def christoffel_at_point_4d(metric, inverse_metric, t, r, theta, phi, dims):
    coord = torch.tensor([t, r, theta, phi], requires_grad=True)
    g_inv = inverse_metric(coord)
    jacobian = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(metric, coord, create_graph=True)
    return calculate_christoffel(jacobian, g_inv, dims)

def kerr_metric(coords, M=15000, a=0.97):
    t = coords[0]
    r = coords[1]
    theta = coords[2]
    phi = coords[3]
    sigma = r ** 2 + a ** 2 * torch.cos(theta) ** 2
    delta = r ** 2 - 2 * M * r + a ** 2
    return torch.tensor([
        [-(1 - (2 * M * r) /sigma), 0., 0., -((2 * M * r * a * torch.sin(theta) ** 2) / sigma)],
        [0., sigma / delta, 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., sigma, 0.],
        [-((2 * M * r * a * torch.sin(theta) ** 2) / sigma), 0., 0., (r ** 2 + a ** 2 + (2 * M * r * a ** 2)/sigma * torch.sin(theta) ** 2) * torch.sin(theta) ** 2]
    ])

def kerr_inverse_metric(coords, M=15000, a=0.97):
    # Based off https://www.roma1.infn.it/teongrav/onde19_20/kerr.pdf
    t = coords[0]
    r = coords[1]
    theta = coords[2]
    phi = coords[3]
    sigma = r ** 2 + a ** 2 * torch.cos(theta) ** 2
    delta = r ** 2 - 2 * M * r + a ** 2
    return torch.tensor([
        [-1 / delta * (r ** 2 + a ** 2 + (2 * M * r * a ** 2) / sigma * torch.sin(theta) ** 2), 0., 0., -(2 * M * r * a) / (sigma * delta)],
        [0., delta / sigma, 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1 / sigma, 0.],
        [-(2 * M * r * a) / (sigma * delta), 0., 0., (delta - a ** 2 * torch.sin(theta) ** 2) / (sigma * delta * torch.sin(theta) ** 2)]
    ])

def kerr_d_ds(X, s, metric=kerr_metric, inverse_metric=kerr_inverse_metric):
    """
    The value of the first and second
    derivatives with respect to an affine
    parameter s
    """
    # Create a new vector to hold the positions and velocities
    u = np.zeros(X.shape)
    # X is a vector with 4 components of position
    # and 4 components of velocity
    x = X[:4]
    velocities = X[4:]
    # Find christoffel symbols given the position and the metric
    # here t is coordinate time, not the affine parameter s, and
    # also not the proper time
    x0, x1, x2, x3 = x
    Gamma = christoffel_at_point_4d(metric, inverse_metric, x0, x1, x2, x3, 4)
    # Given the christoffel symbols, calculate the next position
    for mu in range(4):
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                # Solve for x components
                # we sum due to the Einstein summation convention
                u[mu] += -Gamma[mu][i][j] * velocities[i] * velocities[j]
    # Solve for v components
    u[4:] = velocities
    return u

def rk4(f, u0, t0, tf, n):
    """
    Expects a function in the form y' = f(y, t) to solve
    f - function, MUST return numpy array of derivatives
    u0 - initial values
    t0 - initial time
    tf - final time
    n - number of samples
    """
    t = np.linspace(t0, tf, n+1)
    u = np.zeros((n+1, len(u0)))
    u[0] = u0
    h = t[1]-t[0]
    for i in range(n):
        k1 = h * f(u[i], t[i])    
        k2 = h * f(u[i] + 0.5 * k1, t[i] + 0.5*h)
        k3 = h * f(u[i] + 0.5 * k2, t[i] + 0.5*h)
        k4 = h * f(u[i] + k3, t[i] + h)
        u[i+1] = u[i] + (k1 + 2*(k2 + k3 ) + k4) / 6
    return u, t

c = 1 # as we use geometrized units
r0 = 6 * 15000 # orbital radius of 6M
theta0 = np.pi / 4 # if we use pi / 2 we get NaNs
phi0 = 0
v_r0 = c
v_theta0 = 0
v_phi0 = 0
u0 = np.array([0, r0, theta0, phi0, 0, v_r0, v_theta0, v_phi0])

tf = 1500

x_sol, t_sol = rk4(kerr_d_ds, u0, 0, tf, 50)

r = x_sol[:,1]
theta = x_sol[:,2]
phi = x_sol[:,3]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

x = r * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
y = r * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
z = r * np.cos(theta)

ax.plot3D(x, y, z)
ax.set_title("Null geodesics 3D plot")
plt.show()
```

However, when I run the solver, this is the value of $r$:

```
array([90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000.,
       90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000.,
       90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000.,
       90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000.,
       90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000.,
       90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000., 90000.,
       90000., 90000., 90000.])
```

I'm wondering why the radial, as well as azimuthal and polar velocities, are constant. I would not expect that a photon placed at an orbit of $6M$ from a Kerr black hole would suddenly stop moving. I've already factored out issues relating to the photon being too close to the event horizon/ergospheres or numerical precision errors, so why does the solver show this result?

Comment: We don’t debug code on this site.

Comment: $v^\mu = \langle 0, c, 0, 0 \rangle$ is not a null vector.

Comment: It's probably a bit too technical for SO, and it's unlikely that anyone without GR expertise would be able to offer much help. Have you tried the simpler problem of null geodesics in a plain Schwarzschild metric?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes indeed I have, the same issue arises with a plain Schwarzschild metric, but I will definitely try debugging with the simpler Schwarzschild metric

Comment: You may enjoy [Divergent reflections around the photon sphere of a black hole](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-93595-w) by Albert Sneppen. I have a simple integrator for Schwarzschild photon trajectories (in Sage/Python) here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/680961/123208

Comment: $v^\mu = \langle 1, 1, 0, 0 \rangle$ Is a null vector in Minkowski spacetime, but I don’t think it’s a null vector in Kerr spacetime.

Comment: -1 If we *did* debug code, you would have to provide a debuggable program. I don’t see anywhere that you call rk4 or kerr_d_ds, so how could your program calculate anything?

Comment: The components on the null vector should be set such that $g_{ab}v^av^b = 0$

Comment: @Ghoster Thank you for pointing out these things! I have been very sloppy in asking questions, and you have lead me to recognize the areas in which I am lacking in relativity! Fixed the code where I forgot to add the call to the solver

Answer (score 1):

The issue I found after research is with the way Pytorch calculates the Jacobian. To calculate the correct Jacobian, the metric must be explicitly defined, like so:

```
def kerr_metric(coords, M=15000, a=0.97):
    t = coords[0]
    r = coords[1]
    theta = coords[2]
    phi = coords[3]
    sigma = r ** 2 + a ** 2 * torch.cos(theta) ** 2
    delta = r ** 2 - 2 * M * r + a ** 2
    g = torch.zeros(4, 4)
    g[0][0] = -(1 - (2 * M * r) /sigma)
    g[0][3] = -(2 * M * r * a * torch.sin(theta) ** 2) / sigma
    g[1][1] = sigma / delta
    g[2][2] = sigma
    g[3][0] = -(2 * M * r * a * torch.sin(theta) ** 2) / sigma
    g[3][3] = (r ** 2 + a ** 2 + (2 * M * r * a ** 2)/sigma * torch.sin(theta) ** 2) * torch.sin(theta) ** 2
    return g

def kerr_inverse_metric(coords, M=15000, a=0.97):
    # Based off https://www.roma1.infn.it/teongrav/onde19_20/kerr.pdf
    t = coords[0]
    r = coords[1]
    theta = coords[2]
    phi = coords[3]
    sigma = r ** 2 + a ** 2 * torch.cos(theta) ** 2
    delta = r ** 2 - 2 * M * r + a ** 2
    g_inv = torch.zeros(4, 4)
    g_inv[0][0] = -1 / delta * (r ** 2 + a ** 2 + (2 * M * r * a ** 2) / sigma * torch.sin(theta) ** 2)
    g_inv[0][3] = -(2 * M * r * a) / (sigma * delta)
    g_inv[1][1] = delta / sigma
    g_inv[2][2] = 1 / sigma
    g_inv[3][0] = -(2 * M * r * a) / (sigma * delta)
    g_inv[3][3] = (delta - a ** 2 * torch.sin(theta) ** 2) / (sigma * delta * torch.sin(theta) ** 2)
    return g_inv
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76022365/why-does-the-jacobian-of-the-metric-tensor-give-zero