# Energy of circle orbit in Schwarzschild metric

Tags: general-relativity, energy, differential-geometry, orbital-motion, invariants

For Schwarzschild metric we have invariants:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
& r^2 \frac{d \varphi}{d \tau}=\frac{L}{m} \\
& \left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right) \frac{d t}{d \tau}=\frac{E}{m c^2} .
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Which, after being put into metric give us orbit equation:
\begin{equation}
    \left(\frac{d r}{d \varphi}\right)^2=\frac{r^4}{b^2}-\left(1-\frac{r_s}{r}\right)\left(\frac{r^4}{a^2}+r^2\right),
\end{equation}
If I set left part as zero for circle orbit, I still have no particular solution for E and L, the same orbit allows different energies and angular momentums. Such indetermenism confuses me, what am I doin wrong?

Comment: As I mention [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/680961/123208), the equations are simpler if we use the parameter $u=\frac{r_s}r$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requiring that $\frac{dr}{d\varphi}=0$ at a particular value of $r$ is not sufficient to guarantee that the orbit is circular. It only tells you that the orbit has a turning point at $r$. For each $r>r_s$ there is a one parameter family of orbits that have a turning point at that $r$.

To ensure that orbit is circular you need to also require that $\frac{d^2r}{d\varphi^2}=0$.

Comment: but it doesn't give any information, because $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial \varphi}\neq f(\varphi)$

Comment: If $r$ is a function of $\varphi$ so is $\frac{dr}{d\varphi}$.

Comment: ok thanks, seems like it's very complex equation