# Obtaining Geodesic equation for Massive particles using Schwarzschild metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, geodesics

Geodesic equations for the metric $$dS^2 = \left(1 - \dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)\dot t^2 - \dfrac{\dot r^2}{\left(1-\dfrac{2GM}{r}\right)} - r^2\left(\dot \phi^2\right),$$ would be

$$\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{r}\right)\dot t = k$$
$$\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{r}\right)\dot t^2 - \frac{\dot r^2}{\left(1 - \frac{2GM}{r}\right)} - r^2\dot\phi^2 = 1$$
$$r^2\dot\phi^2 = h$$

where h = J(angular momentum)/m and k = E/m and c = 1. I obtain the first and third one but stuck with the second problem. Please Help

Reference: General Relativity by Hobson (Section 9.6)

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Please solve", what have you tried so far?

Comment: ok, let me show my result

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772180/123208

Comment: Your photos gave me eye cancer, next time use a proper scanner or even better Latex.

Comment: Sorry, for the trouble, tommorow got exam on General relativity  :(

Comment: @PhysicsLover - no problem since you're still new. If you have little time to prepare for the test take a look [here](http://relativity.yukterez.net/06.html#8) at Input/Output 8 for the 2nd order geodesic equation derived over the Christoffel symbols, that can also manage turning points which the 1st order ones can't.

Comment: ok, I give a look into it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equation doesn't really come from the Euler-Lagrange equations (though one could probably derive it from them.)  It's much easier to see from the definition of the particle's proper time:
$$
d\tau^2 = g_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu.
$$
Expand out the sum above, divide both sides by $d\tau^2$, and you'll get the equation you want.

Comment: ok, understood. I thought we obtain second equation in similar fashion as first and third is obtained XD